# Access Select IN using VBA function

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have this SQL Query

```
SELECT *
FROM [Employee To Manager]
WHERE [Employee To Manager].[Manager UID] In(getMyTeamUserNames());
```

Which has a VBA function getMyTeamUserNames()

```
Public Function getMyTeamUserNames() As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
getMyTeamUserNames = commaDelimitArray(getTeamUserNames(getUserName, dbs))
End Function

Public Function commaDelimitArray(arrayStr) As String
Dim sepStr As String
sepStr = "','"
commaDelimitArray = "'" & Join(arrayStr, sepStr)

End Function
Public Function getTeamUserNames(username, dbs) As String()

Dim sqlstatement As String
sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM [Employee to Manager] WHERE [Employee to 
Manager].[Manager UID] = '" & username & "'"
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlstatement, dbOpenSnapshot)
Dim ComputerUsernames() As String
Dim FindRecordCount As Integer
   If rs.EOF Then
  FindRecordCount = 0
  Exit Function
  Else
  rs.MoveLast
  FindRecordCount = rs.RecordCount
  End If
   ReDim ComputerUsernames(FindRecordCount) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 0
   rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
      ComputerUsernames(i) = rs("Computer Username")
        If (ComputerUsernames(i) <> "") Then
                i = i + 1
        End If
    If (ComputerUsernames(i - 1) <> username) Then
      Dim recurResult() As String
      recurResult = getTeamUserNames(ComputerUsernames(i - 1), dbs)

      Dim resultSize As Integer
      If Len(Join(recurResult)) > 0 Then
      resultSize = UBound(recurResult) - LBound(recurResult) + 1
      ReDim Preserve ComputerUsernames(UBound(ComputerUsernames) + resultSize)
      For Each resultStr In recurResult
      ComputerUsernames(i) = resultStr
        If (ComputerUsernames(i) <> "") Then
                i = i + 1
        End If
      Next resultStr
      End If
    End If
      rs.MoveNext
Loop
ReDim Preserve ComputerUsernames(i - 1)
getTeamUserNames = ComputerUsernames
End Function
```

Query runs and I get no data.
However if I take the result from getMyTeamUserNames() and put it in the query by hand it works. getMyTeamUserNames() result varies from possibly 2 results to 40 (recursively gets subordinates all the way down the tree).

Comment: The SQL IN expression expects a list of values either 1) explicitly listed or 2) returned by another SQL subquery.  The SQL engine will interpret a string returned from a VBA function as a single value even if the string itself is formatted as a list.  There is no dynamic interpretation of the string value returned by the function.  The SQL query will therefore only match a if a **single** [Manager UID] column value contains (i.e. is equal to) a list of values - not likely. It is tempting to answer the question with alternatives, but you can search for those separately.

Comment: Instead of dynamic parameter in query, set the filter property of form or use WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenForm/OpenReport. Why do you need to build a set and not just use `username` criteria used for the RecordSet object?

Comment: FYI: I would avoid recursion with SQL queries even for hierarchical data. Instead, it should be much faster to open a single recordset into memory then use the Recordset.FindFirst() method (or other find methods) to search for related row.  The Recordset.Bookmark property can also be useful in this case--for resetting the position as you iterate.  (Pure SQL coupled with appropriately indexed tables is usually the most efficient query path, but the overhead of executing separate queries and retrieving a new recordset has a lot of overhead even within VBA in Access.)

Comment: P.S. The commaDelimitArray() function leaves a dangling apostrophe on the list.  So even if the original query would have worked, the list was not being formatted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a C Perkins specifically pointed out this would never work so I have rebuilt the query with some other queries.